# Declare a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my query

```
DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(3)

SET @DB = 'PK1'

SELECT DATA FROM +@DB+_ADD
```

I get an error message

> incorrect syntax near +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is an operator that works on *values*, such as constants, functions, and columns.  It doesn't work on identifiers within the query.  You can do what you want with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(3);
SET @DB = 'PK1';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT DATA FROM ' + @DB_ + 'ADD';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input....

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic sql for this, something like....

```
DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DB = 'PK1'

SET @Sql = N'SELECT DATA FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DB+'_ADD');

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```